# Turning Bokeh code into executable with py2exe error

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe, bokeh

I'm trying to turn [this Bokeh example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/categorical.html) into an executable with py2exe but I get a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error when I try it.

Has anybody had any luck turning Bokeh code into an executable with py2exe? Are there any additional options I need to define in my setup.py file?

I am using Python 2.7 with Bokeh 0.9.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase recursion depth limit by adding this line at the beginning of your file:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Now I'm dealing with different issues. Thanks!